How to solve WSL2 showing error code 130 when closing it with Ctrl+D
When I press Ctrl+D I get error
[process exited with code 130 (0x00000082)]
You can now close this terminal with Ctrl+D, or press Enter to restart

When then press it again it closes. (As I'd expect it to on the first try)
My context:
Windows 11 Enterprise
Version 10.0.22631 Build 22631
Existing solutions are either out-of-date or not working

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4989
https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/7306
https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/5214


Even if this is off-topic here (as not related to programming): please share all text content in text form, not embedded in screenshots

@NicoHaase done, is this better?


Go to WSL2 settings.
Open the terminal, next to the tab there's a plus and and arrow down [+|v].
Click on the arrow down
Settings
Select your Linux machine on the left page
Scroll down to Advanced settings
Search for Set Profile termination behavior
Set it to Close when process exits, fails or crashes
Save


The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.
